# Accountant rounding in swift

Tags: swift, rounding

I'm not aware how to round numbers in the following manner in Swift:

6.51,6.52,6.53, 6.54 should be rounded down to 6.50

6.56, 6.57, 6.58, 6.59 should be rounded down to 6.55

I have already tried

```
func roundDown(number: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
    return floor(number / toNearest) * toNearest
}
```

to no success. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Doesn't `roundDown(number: 6.56, toNearest: 0.05)`  give what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's it ! I completely missed it. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example where it fails: `roundDown(number: 100.1, toNearest: 0.05)` gives `100.05` instead of the expected `100.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem (and it has nothing to do with Swift whatsoever): Floating point arithmetic is not exact. Let's say you try to divide 6.55 by 0.05 and expect a result of 131.0. In reality, 6.55 is "some number close to 6.55" and 0.05 is "some number close to 0.05", so the result that you get is "some number close to 131.0". That result is likely just a tiny little bit smaller than 131.0, maybe 130.999999999999 and floor () returns 130.0.

What you do: You decide what is the smallest number that you still want to round up. For example, you'd want 130.999999999999 to give a result of 131.0. You'd probably want 130.9999 to give a result of 131.0. So change your code to

```
floor (number * 20.0 + 0.0001);
```

This will round 6.549998 to 6.55, so check if you are Ok with that. Also, floor () works in an unexpected way for negative input, so -6.57 would be rounded down to -6.60, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: I don't want to round 6.54 to 6.55, but to 6.50. roundDown(number: 6.56, toNearest: 0.05)

Comment: There is no way that guarantees that 6.55 will be rounded to 6.55 unless you accept that some smaller numbers are round to 6.55 as well. Change that from "no way" to "no f***ing way". And this _does_ round 6.54 to 6.5.